# Perl: Open output file in same endianess as input file – UTF-16be vs. UTF-16le

Tags: perl, encoding, endianness, utf-16

When Perl opens an UTF-16 encoded file,

`open my $in, "< :encoding(UTF-16)", "text-utf16le.txt" or die "Error $!\n";`

it automatically detects the [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) thanks [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

But when I open file for writing

`open my $out, "> :encoding(UTF-16)", "output.txt" or die "Error $!\n";`

Perl opens it as big endian by default.

How to specify to open output file in the same endianness as input file, please?

How to get endianness/encoding from the input file handle `$in`? `PerlIO::get_layers($in)` returns among other layers `encoding(UTF-16)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to read the BOM yourself.

```
use IO::Unread qw( unread );

open(my $fh_in, "<:raw", $qfn)
   or die;

my $rv = read($fh_in, my $buf, 4);
defined($rv)
   or die;

my $encoding;
my $bom_present;
if    ($buf =~ s/^\x00\x00\xFE\xFF//) { $encoding = 'UTF-32be'; $bom_present = 1; }
elsif ($buf =~ s/^\xFF\xFE\x00\x00//) { $encoding = 'UTF-32le'; $bom_present = 1; }
elsif ($buf =~ s/^\xFE\xFF//        ) { $encoding = 'UTF-16be'; $bom_present = 1; }
elsif ($buf =~ s/^\xFF\xFE//        ) { $encoding = 'UTF-16le'; $bom_present = 1; }
elsif ($buf =~ s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//    ) { $encoding = 'UTF-8';    $bom_present = 1; }
else {
   $encoding = 'UTF-8';
   $bom_present = 0;
}

unread($fh_in, $buf) if length($buf);

binmode($fh_in, ":encoding($encoding)");
binmode($fh_in, ":crlf") if $^O eq 'MSWin32';
```

But someone's already done that for you:

```
use File::BOM qw( open_bom );

my $encoding = open_bom(my $fh_in, $qfn, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
```